# inline-c : "`Type` cannot be marshalled in a foreign call"

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, c2hs

#### Setting

A C enum type rendered into Haskell by c2hs, complete with `Storable` instance which compiles correctly (`TypesC2Hs.chs`). I import this unqualified into the module I have assigned for the `inline-c` context (`Internal.hs`). Both the `.hs` module generated by c2hs and `Internal.hs` are imported by `InlineC.hs`, the other `inline-c` module that holds the quasiquotes wrapping the C calls.

```
TypesC2Hs.hs ------------- 
    |                    |
    V                    V
Internal.hs -------> InlineC.hs
```

#### Question

`InlineC.hs` complains that this type cannot be marshalled: "Unacceptable argument type in foreign declaration: ‘DMBoundaryType’ cannot be marshalled in a foreign call When checking declaration:"

What is going on? This is the first time `inline-c` gives me type of this error.

I should note that other types that do not need to be dereferenced directly, e.g. `newtype DM = DM (Ptr DM) deriving Storable`, work fine with the above approach.

Thanks in advance

---

TypesC2Hs.chs

```
{# enum DMBoundaryType as DMBoundaryType {underscoreToCase} deriving (Eq, Show) #}

instance Storable DMBoundaryType where
  sizeOf _ = {# sizeof DMBoundaryType #}
  alignment _ = {# alignof DMBoundaryType #}
  peek = peek
  poke = poke
```

Internal.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell ,GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, StandaloneDeriving ,DeriveDataTypeable, DataKinds, OverloadedStrings #-}

module Internal where

import TypesC2Hs

import qualified Language.C.Inline         as C
import qualified Language.C.Types          as CT
import           Language.C.Inline.Context

import qualified Language.Haskell.TH       as TH

import           Data.Monoid               ((<>), mempty)
import qualified Data.Map                  as Map


ctx :: Context
ctx = baseCtx <> funCtx <> vecCtx <> bsCtx <> pctx where
  pctx = mempty {ctxTypesTable = typesTable}


typesTable :: Map.Map CT.TypeSpecifier TH.TypeQ  
typesTable = Map.fromList
              [ (CT.TypeName "DMBoundaryType", [t| DMBoundaryType |])  ]
```

InlineC.hs

```
dmdaCreate1d0' cc bx m dof s =
   withPtr ( \ dm -> [C.exp|int{DMDACreate1d($(int c),
                                              $(DMBoundaryType bx),
                                              $(PetscInt m),
                                              $(PetscInt dof),
                                              $(PetscInt s),
                                              NULL,
                                              $(DM* dm))}|]  )
  where c = unComm cc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C `enum` is not [marshallable foreign type](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1560008.4.2), that is what compiler tries to tell you. To work around it, pass it as a `CInt` using `fromEnum` (looks like `c2hs` now supports it via [hooks](https://github.com/haskell/c2hs/wiki/Implementation%20of%20Haskell%20Binding%20Modules#enumeration-hooks), but I never tried it.)

Comment: Thank you; so IIUC for every C enum I will need two Haskell types and the respective conversion functions, e.g.
`{# enum DMBoundaryType as DMBoundaryType_ {underscoreToCase} deriving (Eq, Show) #}
type DMBoundaryType = {# type DMBoundaryType #}

dmbToC x = toCInt $ fromEnum (x :: DMBoundaryType_)
dmbFromC c = (toEnum $ fromIntegral (c :: DMBoundaryType)):: DMBoundaryType_`.
Since I have a few tens of these enum types, what is a good way to do this without much copy/paste? A C macro?